# How to find and reduce log events generated by Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I think the word 'log' is used in more than one way when it comes to Kafka. I'm talking about log output that ends up in stdout or your-app.log or splunk/datadog/etc.

Every 30 seconds, *something* happens 3 times. And each time it happens, approximately 65 log events appear. I'm wondering

1. What is this *something*?
2. Can I cause all of its output to appear on a single line? (My log 'provider' charges per log event, and each line counts as a separate event.)

The logs are like this:

```
INFO  - Kafka version: ...
INFO  - Kafka commitId: ...
INFO  - Kafka startTimeMs: ...
INFO  - App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-...
INFO  - Metrics scheduler closed
INFO  - Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
INFO  - Metrics reporters closed
INFO  - AdminClientConfig values: 
bootstrap.servers = [...
foo = ...
bar = ...
baz = ...
qux = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line is an Slf4j event. If you want to change its format from your client or the broker, you'll need to modify your logging framework configurations. In the broker, you'll find a `log4j.properties` file.

All output cannot appear in a single line. Each `INFO`, for example, is an individual event. These can be *reduced* by disabling the logs for the Java packages that print them.

The alternative is to install some other log forwarder on your systems like Fluentd and parse/filter/forward data using that.

Comment: Also, what is Kafka doing every 30 seconds? Maybe I can configure it to not print AdminClientConfig values

Comment: The AdminClient is generally used to create topics, for the most part, or maybe lookup other brokers, but by default, I can't think of anything that runs every 30 seconds on the broker